# Filter Pandas dataframe by most recent date for each unique column value

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have a dataframe:

```
      Col1          timestamp

1    x20034   2019-11-19 14:56:51
2    x20035   2019-11-20 12:16:22
3    x20035   2019-12-09 17:47:44
4    x20037   2019-12-08 17:47:44
5    x20037   2019-12-09 18:47:44
6    x20037   2019-12-10 22:47:40
```

And I need:

```
1    x20034   2019-11-19 14:56:51
2    x20035   2019-11-20 12:16:22
6    x20037   2019-12-10 22:47:40
```

I tried:

```
df[df['timestamp'] == df['timestamp'].max()]
```

Is this the best/only way?

Comment: `df = df.groupby('Col1')['timestamp'].max().reset_index()` is another way. Your current way is not doing it per group.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `transform`

```
out = df[df['timestamp'] == df.groupby('Col1')['timestamp'].transform('max')]
```